# Reading from Json File garbage after json object

Tags: json, perl

I'm using json file in a Perl program. I'm unable to parse the json file.

It is giving following error:

```
garbage after JSON object, at character offset 2326471 (before "{"response":{"numFou...") at /usr/local/share/perl5/JSON.pm line 171, <$f> line 1.
```

Here is the code:

```
print "input json";
open(my $f, "<", "$ARGV[1]");
my $content=<$f>;
my $structured;
eval {
$structured = from_json($content, {utf8 => 1});
};

if ($@) {
   $content =~ s/\n/ /g;
   my $errMsg = $@;
   $errMsg =~ s/\n/ /g;
   WriteInfo("Unparseable result for url=$url, error: $errMsg\n") ;
};
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your json is invalid but you want to repair it?

Comment: I'm new to json so i dont know whether my input file ( that is json ) is only corrupted. How Can i repair it anyways.?

Comment: It would be difficult, perhaps impossible; better question is why it is corrupted in the first place.

Comment: It seems like it's a pretty big JSON file. You could load it into a text editor that supports auto-indenting/beautifying JSON and see what happens. If this is a one-time thing you might be able to fix it manually. If it's a regular import, you need to talk to the soruce of the data to find a solution. And of course find out why it is invalid.

Comment: Try pushing the JSON through an online JSON validator. If it finds the problem then you can ask the people who supply the JSON to try the same test.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I fix this error?

You can't fix JSON data automatically. There could be many "fixes" that will get the data through the parser, but it may be difficult to tell which of them is the correct one. You should talk to the source of the data and ask for a correct version

It may be possible to fix the data manually, but you should only attempt this if there is no correct version of the data available. Finding the error in a 2.2MB+ text file by hand isn't a trivial job, and the character position 2326471 is only where the parser *found* an error, not where the correction should be made

> garbage after JSON object ...

This implies that `from_json` has found the end of the JSON data -- i.e. the final closing brace `}` or bracket `]` -- but there is data in the string after that character. It may be that the file has been written correctly, but there really is spurious data after the end of the JSON. If so then that should be obvious just by examining the data file

#### Note

Unless you have redefined the `$/` variable, these lines

```
open(my $f, "<", "$ARGV[1]");
my $content = <$f>;
```

will read just the *first line* of the file into `$content`. It may be that the file contains just a single very long line of tex (i.e. it contains no newline characters) but this line in your error handler

```
$content =~ s/\n/ /g;
```

implies that ther *are* newlines in there.

Reading only the first line of a multi-line JSON file wouldn't cause the error that you're seeing, but it is best to read the entire file into memory before decoding it as JSON data, just in case unexpected newlines have crept into the data

Here is a better way of writing your code segment

```
print "Input JSON\n";

my $content - do {
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1] or die qq{Unable to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!};
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};


my $structured = eval {
    from_json( $content, {utf8 => 1} );
};

if ( my $err_msg = $@ ) {

   $content =~ tr/\n/ /;
   $err_msg =~ tr/\n/ /;

   WriteInfo("Unparsable result for URL=$url, error: $err_msg\n") ;
};
```

Comment: Yes, the json file has only single line content. Actually that file is constructed by calling a url several time and writing that content into json. So i thing json file has serveral response feilds in it and it is unable to parse such file. Is it possible to correctly parse a json file which has several responses content at once .?

Comment: I used spilt function in perl to seperate the records and then parse each record which is present in a array. It worked fine. Thanks